# Is there a way to open a website and paste using python?

Tags: python, paste, python-webbrowser

I have some code that relies on google maps to work. When you open [Google Maps](http://google.com/maps) it opens a text-box. And the cursor is open to type. I am using the web browser module and the open function. How could I directly paste to the text-box?

Comment: It would be helpful to show your code and see what you are missing.

Comment: Nonetheless, if you want to automate pasting into the text-box, you might need to use Selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/ If you want to see that in the browser, you would open the url returned by selenium in the webbrowser module.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your use case, perhaps you want to use the API directly instead of opening the browser: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

Comment: I'm just a beginner and I have no idea what an API is

Comment: It sounds like a good time to learn what an API is in the first place. It stands for "Application Programming Interface": in general, it is a layer developed for developers like ourselves of toggle its services through programmatic means like Python. Rather than try to code up something that mimics what a regular person would do with with a browser, keyboard, and mouse, it is generally advisable to use a programming language or service to directly speak with the API.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there is a way to open a website and paste using python with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), and if you want to see it visually, you can use the web browser module in addition to Selenium.

Nevertheless, in your specific scenario, you want to access a Google service. I would recommend using its [API](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) over using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and the webbrowser if you plan to use Google Maps continuously through automation. Google does own [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) which Google will use against any bot-like activities. Again, I am not too sure what your usecase is, but I would generally use an available API over this Selenium automation.

Comment: I have some text which I want my code to open and search for it on google maps. You can't not give the exact location in the search bar. I want to put the text in the maps search area and see the options

Comment: Sounds like the API documentation will answer your question: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/README.md#usage